# How to write a .gitignore to ignore spaces and other characters ?#%: in folders and filenames

Tags: github, character, whitespace

How do I setup the .gitignore file to ignore files with invalid characters like the examples below

WEB FILES

```
foo. js
foo.js <----space after the s

CSS:CSS.css
foo???.html
```

I just want any file with a special character/space to be ignored.  Likewise if I can also apply that to folders.

FOLDERS

```
images <----space after the s
```

I teach a Web Development class for 9-12th graders and use github and it amazes me everyday how kids can find ways to blow up my repository.  These are all examples of files and folders that cause github desktop to not be able to pull origin.

Answer (score 0):

[Git 2.0 mentions](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b02fd2accad4d48078671adf38fe5b5976d77304/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt#L130-L133)

> Trailing whitespaces in .gitignore files, unless they are quoted for fnmatch(3), e.g. "`path\`", are warned and ignored

So in your case, you can:

- add "`*.js\` " to your `.gitignore`
- delete the file or rename it
- check that any new file with a trailing space is indeed ignored.

Comment: As an example: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/526#issuecomment-310594523